# How can i swap matrix 2d in python

Tags: python

I want to swap if the matrix `[i][i]` is 0 but the swap didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as matrix
import sys


rows = int(input("Rows = "))
columns = int(input("Columns = "))

matriks = matrix.zeros((rows,columns))
temp = matrix.zeros((rows,columns))

for i in range(columns):
    for j in range(rows):
        matriks[i][j] = float(input("matrix["+str(i)+"]["+str(j)+"] = "))

for i in range(columns):
    for j in range(rows):
        if matriks[i][i] == 0:
            temp = matriks[i][j]
            matriks[i][j] = matriks[i+1][j]
            matriks[i+1][j] = temp

print(matriks)
```

Example input:

```
[0 1]  
[2 3]
```

Expected output:

```
[2 3]  
[0 1]
```

But the output is:

```
[2 1]  
[0 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use this (if I understand you correctly):

```
matrix = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]

# Swap
matrix[::-1]
>>> [[2, 3], [0, 1]]
```

Which will swap the elements in your matrix (list).

Or if you want a left-right swap

```
[a[::-1] for a in matrix]
>>> [[1,0], [3,2]]
```